# unable to destroy windows 2008 r2 failover cluster after SAN rebuild

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, high-availability, windows-cluster, failovercluster

I created a windows 2008 r2 failover cluster for a sql 2008 active/passive cluster. This two node cluster was using a SAN device for a quorum disk resource as well as MSDTC resource.

Well....I decided to reconfigure the SAN device, but I didn't destroy the cluster first. Now that the quorum disk and mstdc disk are completely gone, the cluster is obviously not working. But, I can't even destroy the cluster and start again. I've tried from the Windows Clustering tool, as well as the command line. I was able to get the cluster service to start using the "/fixquorum" parameter. After doing this I was able to remove the passive node from the cluster, but it wouldn't let me destroy the cluster because the default resource group and msdtc are still attached as resources. I tried to delete these resources from both the GUI tool, as well as command line. It will either freeze for several minutes and crash the program, or once it even BSOD'd the server.

Can someone advise on how to destroy this cluster so I can start over?

Comment: Is uninstalling SQL server an option?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this also in the past when I deployed a failover cluster. One time I fixed it by executing the following PowerShell command:
[Remove-ClusterNode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461001.aspx)
After that I executed the following command to clear the configuration on the node:
[Clear-ClusterNode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460996.aspx)
You have to start the Windows Powershell Modules from the Administrative Tools otherwise these commands won't work. After that I was able to succesful join it to the cluster

If these commands don't work, I'm afraid you have to reinstall the operating system on each node of the cluster.